# How to display XML string in IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I created a control that gets an xml string, I am trying to figure out how to display the xml content well-formatted in IE, instead of a plain string.

Comment: Throw it in an iframe perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

IE is natively able to display xml document, so maybe just an iframe would do the job.

Or, if your string contains line breaks and is indented, you can wrap it in `<pre></pre>` tags.